# Lenovo Legion 7i not booting after RAID 1 setup

Tags: lenovo-laptop, raid-1, intel-rst

I'm trying to get RAID 1 setup on a new Lenovo Legion 7i laptop using the RAID feature in the BIOS. After I create the RAID 1 volume using Intel Rapid Storage Technology, I add the two disks to the RAID volume and reboot. But then it refuses to boot and I get the error, "Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed."

The laptop originally came with a 512GB disk for the C drive, as well as a 1TB disk for the (mostly empty) D drive. I cloned the 512GB disk to the 1TB disk, then replaced the 512GB disk with a new 1TB disk, so I had two 1TB disks.

I then went into the BIOS, clicked "Configuration", then "Storage", then "Intel Rapid Storage Technology", and created a RAID 1 volume containing the two 1TB disks. I saved changes and exited the BIOS, but it reboots to the error mentioned above.

I've tried this several times, and I've verified that after cloning the 512GB disk to the 1TB disk, the 1TB disk is able to boot on its own, so the clone seems to have been successful and it created a bootable disk.

I also tried cloning the 512GB disk to both of the 1TB disks before creating the RAID 1 volume with the 1TB disks but it made no difference.

BIOS version: 4.07

Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: When changing to raid you should reinstall the OS, or clone to the current raid array, better to make a system image and restore the image to the raid array you created.

Comment: @Moab - Thanks, your comment made me realize that when I create the raid volume, it's actually erasing everything on both disks. Which means I need to make a backup image of the Windows drive, then remove the Windows drive and create the raid volume with the two big drives, and then restore the backup onto the raid volume. Which means the restore will need to be done from a bootable USB drive, and the backup will need to be stored on a network drive. The problem I see now is that the restore program will need to restore onto the raid volume that has no drive letter assigned yet. Thoughts?

Comment: It does not need a drive letter, restoring the image to the raid array will do that for you.